# Moodle login after signup

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I'm trying to make my first Moodle auth extension where I want to confirm and login users directly after signup.

I've changed the user_signup function in the "email" auth plugin like this:

```
\core\event\user_created::create_from_userid($user->id)->trigger();

$DB->set_field("user", "confirmed", 1, array("id"=>$user->id));

$user = get_complete_user_data('username', $username);
$DB->set_field("user", "firstaccess", time(), array("id"=>$user->id));
$DB->set_field("user", "lastlogin", 0, array("id"=>$user->id));
update_user_login_times($user);

complete_user_login($user);
redirect("$CFG->wwwroot/enrol/index.php?id=2");
```

It works so far as the user gets signed up and confirmed. But as for the login I get the following error:

core\session\manager::login_user() must be an instance of stdClass, boolean given

I might be acting stupid here, but I don't know how I could login the new user here. Any help would be very much apprechiated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After Creating user account get username and password that you have entered and then implement like this.

```
if ($user = authenticate_user_login($username, $password)) {
/// Let's get them all set up.
        complete_user_login($user);
        redirect($CFG->wwwroot . 'URL you want');
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make something that allows students from any school that uses moodle to login using their moodle sign in?  For example I have a college book rental app , id like to have a "sign in with moodle" button. Possible?

Comment: This functionality is not available with Moodle, but you can create your own API for that to perform sign in with Moodle.

Comment: Thanks Priye, but actually I have no idea how to get the username and password.